# Trouble migrating database tables with groovy sql

Tags: groovy, batch-processing

I want to select data from one table and insert into another in batches, using different sql connections. The two tables are set up exactly the same. At the moment I have:

```
destination.withBatch(1000) { stmt ->

    source.eachRow(selectQuery) {

        String insertString = """
                    INSERT INTO dest_table
                    VALUES (
                          ${it[0]},
                          ${it[1]});
                    """

        try {
            stmt.addBatch(insertString)
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            println insertString
        }
    }
}
```

Something seems to happen to the data types in this process, because it gets very unhappy inserting a string like `'a:string'` because of the colon.

I could do `'${it[0]}'` to enforce it is treated as a String, but this will cause problems when I come to other data types.

Furthermore, my error handling is definitely not working correctly. I want it to print out the inserts that it was unable to execute, and then carry on gracefully.

Thanks

Comment: What is your `selectQuery` and what is the actual Exception?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that groovy sql is creating a prepared statement from your sql string, and that anything with a colon in it is parsed as a parameter placeholder.

So, I'd suggest going with the flow, and binding your data values separately, instead of putting them inline in the sql statement. This will also probably improve performance, as the prepared statements can be cached by the database.